# Jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am in the process of putting together a shared library for my Jenkins builds. I haven't really used groovy much before so at the moment I am following the docs (always a good start :-)) and have created a file located at `/vars/myFile.groovy` for example.

Now I have a list (shortened in the example below) that I need to use and have placed it within a method for now, but am I right in thinking it would be better outside of the method so that it is only instantiated once rather than every time the method is called?

`/vars/myFile.groovy`

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

def slack_handle(String dev_name) {
  developerList = [
     [name: "Richard Lewis", slack_handle: "<@richardlewis123>"],
     [name: "Mark Turner", slack_handle: "<@markTurner123>"]
    ]
  return developerList.find {it['name'] == dev_name}?.get("slack_handle")
}

def other_method() {

}

def another_method() {

}
```

Then in my Jenkinsfile i can just do

```
SLACK_HANDLE = slackNotification.slack_handle("Richard Lewis")
echo "${SLACK_HANDLE}"
"<@richardlewis123>"
```

How can i declare the list outside of the method to then use within my `slack_handle` method in this shared library

I have tried

```
final def developerList = [
     [name: "Richard Lewis", slack_handle: "<@richardlewis123>"],
     [name: "Mark Turner", slack_handle: "<@markTurner123>"]
    ]

def slack_handle(String dev_name) {
  return developerList.find {it['name'] == dev_name}?.get("slack_handle")
}

def other_method() {

}

def another_method() {

}
```

But when the Jenkins job runs `developerList` is undeclared.

So my question is, should the List be declared outside of the method or in this instance is it OK where it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to annotate the List with @Field

```
import groovy.transform.Field

def call(String dev_name) {
    return slack_handle(dev_name)
}

def slack_handle(String dev_name) {
    return developerList.find {it['name'] == dev_name}?.get("slack_handle")
}

def otherMethod() {
    echo "I got called"
}

@Field
def developerList = [
    [name: "Richard Lewis", slack_handle: "<@richardlewis123>"],
    [name: "Mark Turner", slack_handle: "<@markTurner123>"]
]
```

Function can then be used in the Pipeline e.g. the following way:

```
node {
    stage('Call Function') {
        // either
        echo myFile("Mark Turner")
        // or
        echo myFile.slack_handle("Mark Turner")
        myFile.otherMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the assistance, i have updated my question though as i have other methods in the file, which i believe effect the way `call` is used ?

Comment: I tried it also with direct call: Works the same way:
    myFile.slack_handle("Mark Turner") / myFile.other_method()
Modified my post

Comment: Thank you for helping with this, helped me understand a few more things :-)